# Unbuffered output option for LaTeX executable?

Tags: distributions

I am using a editor (gEdit) that, while compiling LaTeX (or executing any code in its embedded *output* window), hangs waiting from the executing code to flush its output and scrolling the text.

Although this is probably a defect of the editor, I found that a workaround is to flush (i.e. the c function `flush`) the program often. However I don't have control over how LaTeX flushes its compilation output.

**Is it possible that there is an option that I can pass to LaTeX to flush the output before ending the compilation?**

I am using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)` in Linux (Fedora).

Comment: I am also using gedit with the embedded terminal window (in Ubuntu), but I can use the editor normally during LaTeX compilation - in other words, I cannot reproduce the problem. Do you use the default terminal plugin from the `gedit-plugins` package?

Comment: @Marijn To be more clear, it is not the terminal but the output windows (corrected) where the "external tools" outputs is dumped. Try compiling with external tools a long document (e.g. with many images).

Comment: In that case I don't fully understand your workflow: what is 'compiling with external tools'? In my case I just type `pdflatex myfile.tex` in the terminal window and the output is also in that window. It is the same for other commands such as `latex`, `tex`, `xelatex`, `xetex`, `lualatex`, `luatex`, `htlatex`, `tex4ht`, `bibtex`, `biber`, `makeindex`, `xindy`, `latexmk`, `arara`, etc, or any tool started with `shell-escape` such as `convert`. So what exactly do you do that uses Tool Output in gedit?

Comment: @Marijn there is a plug in called External Tools that allows you to execute any program over the edited file at the press of a hot key.

Comment: ah, I understand now :) maybe as a workaround you can install https://github.com/corriander/gedit-panel-switcher and then use ctrl-tab, up arrow, enter? Not as fast as a single hotkey but the output will not be stuck.